# Rails app does not read env variables in .bashrc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, environment-variables

I have saved some ENV's in ~/.bashrc, I close and reopened the file and they are there for sure.

.bashrc:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

. /etc/apache2/envvars

# If not running interactively, don't do anything else
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi

PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]${C9_USER}\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$(__git_ps1 " (%s)") $ '

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

export rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1

export TWILIO_SID="AXXXXX81b7eb5aXXXXeXXX6c9bfecX6X"
export TWILIO_TOKEN="XXX87XXXXXXe650ff2XXXXfXXXXX8X2"
export TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER="+147043XXXX"
```

Yet when I tell my rails app to use them, for example use ENV["TWILIO_SID"] in my controller, it does not know them. I tried echoing them out in bash, it's just an empty line, in HTML, also empty line.
I am using c9 cloud IDE, and there is an option to manually enter ENV into the Rails shell, and when I do that, everything works fine. but my assignment asks for bashrc file... why are neither bash nor rails terminal reading my .bashrc? any help?

PS: the overall goal is to just set a UNIX env variable in my Rails app. I cannot use figaro.

PS2: Here is the code in controller where I'm using the variables. When I hard code them, everything works fine, so I know there is something going on with the env variables.

```
require 'twilio-ruby'

def index
end

class TexterController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def text
    @number = params[:number]
    @message = params[:message]

    twilio_sid =  ENV["TWILIO_SID"]
    twilio_token = ENV["TWILIO_TOKEN"]
    twilio_phone_number = ENV["TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER"]

    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(twilio_sid, twilio_token)

    @message = @client.messages.create(
      to: @number,
      from: twilio_phone_number,
      body: @message
    )

      render "pages/text.html.erb"
  end
end
```

Comment: `source ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Tried that already, didn't work:/

Comment: Please add output of `export -p | grep "TWILIO"` and your ruby code to your question.

Comment: `export -p | grep "TWILIO" > output.txt` generates an empty txt file. I did add my code to the question though.

Comment: Please add your ~/.bashrc to your question.

Comment: ~/.bashrc is three lines, the variables I have added in the beginning. I cleared it up.

Comment: How are you you starting your Rails app? It's only going to pick up the values in your `.bashrc` if it is started from a non-login interactive shell run under your user id.

Comment: My bad, .bashrc is actually a big file, will add it to the question now. I found a solution, working now, but still not running them from .bashrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.
Turns out for some reason, even when I source .bashrc, the env variables are not read, but when I added them to .profile they are read and everything works fine.
Even tried adding them to .bashrc and then `source ~/.bashrc` to .profile, but still wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

And here is the reasons why:

To change the environmental variable "permanently" you'll need to consider at least these situations:

- Login/Non-login shell
- Interactive/Non-interactive shell

Bash as login shell will load `/etc/profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, ~/.profile` in the order

Bash as non-login interactive shell will load `~/.bashrc`

Bash as non-login non-interactive shell will load the configuration specified in environment variable ***$BASH_ENV***

Source: [how to permanently set environmental variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables)